# Can't install pg_config for flask app

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, flask, pip

I am running the following command

> pip install -r .\requirements.txt

in the project directory and get the following error

```
Using cached psycopg2-2.5.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\eugene~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mil943\psy
copg2

Comment: Do you even have Postgres installed?

Comment: yes! it's in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin has to been in environment path